# Creating DOM by PHP vs JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, performance

Currently I don't have any ajax request in my website and here is a simplified of my code:

```
class all_posts {

    public function index($id){

        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
        $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

        $arr = [];
        $arr['html'] = '<ul>';

        // creating HTML
        foreach( $results as $result ) {
           $arr['html'] .= "<li class='clsname'>".$result['title']."</li>
                            <li style='color:gray;'>".$result['content']."</li>";
        }   

        $arr['html'] .= '</ul>';

        return $arr;

    }

}
```

Ok all fine. Now sometimes I want to get the result through ajax request. Well **what's my question?**

I want to know, should I return the result with along the HTML or should I return the pure-query-result and then make the HTML by JS ? In other word which one has a better performance?

**#1:**

```
.
.
$arr['html'] .= '</ul>';

if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) &&
   strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest") {

   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($arr);
   exit();
}

return $arr;
.
.
```

**#2:**

```
.
.
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) &&
   strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest") {

   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($results);
   exit();
}
.
.
```

I personally like to go with **#1**, because in this case I make the HTML once and I can change it later simply. But I'm worried about the performance, will it not be slow?

Comment: When you move the dom creation to the client you should save on both bandwidth and processing time. I would just send the html for simplicity.

Comment: So your choose is the **#1** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have three performances here: server-side, network and client-side.

If you generate the HTML on server-side and send it to the browser, then your server will have to generate that output, the browser will need to extract it as an input and will write it to the DOM. This approach makes the server-side and the network parts slow, but the client-side will be quick. If you send only the data as a response to the client-side, then the server will have less work to do, the network will have to transfer a much smaller message, but the client-side will have to work out all the details. In this case, your server-side and message transfer will be quicker, but your client-side will be slower. Sending only the data will result in better overall performance.

However, I think performance is not the main issue here, unless you have very large chunks of results. It is more important to make sure you are using the same code for initial load and for POST response, to improve maintainability.

Comment: "*However, I think performance is not the main issue here, unless you have very large chunks of results.*". What do you mean "very large" exactly? Is **8KB** called very large?

Comment: @MartinAJ 8KB is not large in this context in my opinion.

Comment: I see. thank you .. just as a note, I guess if I set the web service to return all ajax requests as *.gzip* format, I guess that **8KB** will be almost **1KB** .. Do you know how can I tell to *nginx* to do so?

Comment: @MartinAJ I am not an nginx expert, but I would read the following article if I wanted to make sure nginx responds in gzip: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly why create an array to hold text (a string), completely not worth it.

Anyhow, your better to use json as the transport method and js as the way to create the html that is added.  Using PHP to build HTML will only bring much larger data packets transferred.

Use Some sort of templating engine for JS is best for this, such as Handlebars, Angular or whatever you fancy.  Of course if you have only one AJAX call with one layout, then building vanilla JS document fragments and inserting them is better.

You really should not send the complete SQL output to the client to be worked on, only the content that is actually needed.  i.e. row ID is not needed, created time is not needed, last edit is not needed etc etc

Lastly you need some sort of success/failure field on your JSON so that you can process it as needed.  example

```
$output = array('status'=> 'success', 'data' => $content);
json_encode($output);
```

Thus if there is no data replied by the SQL query you can deal with that.

Comment: Your answer contains some great points related to my question. thank you  and upvote. But actually I don't want any third option, I want to know, which one is your choose between **#1** and **#2** ?

Comment: errr #2 but your doing it wrong like I explained above